# showing a double value in a custom cell in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview, double

So, full disclosure: I'm a newbie to Swift.

I'm working on an app, trying to get a label in a custom cell to display a DOUBLE value. I've tried to do an if let conditional binding to cast it from a string to a double, but my source isn't an optional type, and I can't make it optional. So I'm not sure how to do this.

Here are the specific errors: 
**initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double'** 
**Cannot assign value of type 'Double?' to type 'String?'** 
**No exact matches in call to initializer**

and here's the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoTableViewCell
        
        cell.partNameLabel.text = parts[indexPath.row].partName
        
        // Convert string value to double
        if let value = parts[indexPath.row].partCost {
             cell.partCostLabel.text = Double(value)
        } else {
            cell.partCostLabel.text = 0.00
        }
        cell.purchaseDateLabel.text = parts[indexPath.row].purchaseDate

        return cell
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it looks like `parts[indexPath.row].partCost` is *already* a `Double` -- the error is telling you `if let` only works with `Optional` types.

So, you can replace your `if let / else` block with:

```
cell.partCostLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", parts[indexPath.row].partCost)
```

`cell.partCostLabel.text = 0.00` doesn't work because `Text` expects a `String` -- you won't need this anymore with the above code, but the way to handle it would be `cell.partCostLabel.text = "0.00"`

Finally, `Cannot assign value of type 'Double?' to type 'String?'` -- I'm not sure what line that's occurring on, but if it's `cell.purchaseDateLabel.text = parts[indexPath.row].purchaseDate`  then that means that `purchaseDate` is a `Double?` and you're trying to set it to something that expects a `String`. You will need to consider how you're going to convert a `Double` to a date, but *this one* might be the one where you need `if let`:

```
if let purchaseDate = parts[indexPath.row].purchaseDate {
  cell.purchaseDateLabel.text = "\(purchaseDate)" //you probably want a different way to display this, though
}
```